How to call make ref wait until functions complete to be executed in dispose()?
I have functions that use riverpod in Flutter project.
Future<void> _deleteChatRoom() async {
    try {
      await ref.read(chatRepo).deleteChatRoom(_roomId);
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("_deleteChatRoom -> $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> _updateChatTime() async {
    Duration duration = DateTime.now().difference(_chatStartTime);
    int chatTime = duration.inSeconds;

    await ref.read(chatRepo).updateChatTime(_roomId, chatTime);
  }

And when user exit this Widget, I need to run these functions.
So in dispose() method, I run them before super.dispose().
@override
  void dispose() {
    if (chatList.isEmpty) {
      _deleteChatRoom();
    } else {
      _updateChatTime();
    }

    _messageController.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _answerTypingController.close();
    _animationController.dispose();

    _speechToText.stop();
    _flutterTts.stop();

    super.dispose();
  }

But still I get error:
Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed.
I tried to make super.dispose() to be run after 2 seconds.
 Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      super.dispose();
    });

But it crashes in dispose() part.
And also I can't make dispose() to be async/ await.
How to make this work?

Because the dispose function cannot be async, and even if the Future.delayed worked it would not be the best solution, you could consider a workaround to solve this problem.
I have 2 suggestions:
1st You can wrap your widget with the PopScope widget, and before "exiting" your widget you can run the _deleteChatRoom(), and the _updateChatTime() methods, and then manually call the navigation pop method which will trigger the dispose method, and close the widget.
(In case you have another way of exiting the widget, e.g. an "x" button, you can move those methods calls there)
2nd I am not aware of the architecture of your app, but I guess you could change the scope of the ref variable so you could call the _deleteChatRoom(), and the _updateChatTime() method without depending on the child widget.
Important
Because there is not enough code this solution may not be 100% applicable but you could get a hint on how to solve your problem. It would be best if you could provide more info on how your widgets are organized, and which way of navigation, and state management you are using.
